# isolating name from string

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to figure the correct regex to extract a player name from a string. In some cases there are two sets of parenthesis before the name as shown in the code below: Basically, in both cases, I'm tyring to extract "K. Collins"

```
(6:57) K.Collins pass incomplete short right to A.Crumpler. Coverage by #56 Woodley, #22 Gay.
(6:52) (Shotgun) K.Collins pass incomplete short right to B.Scaife (T.Polamalu).
```

Comment: it might help in future to also extract the second name too if possible. (aka: "A. Crumpler" and "B. Scaife" respectively.

Comment: What format is your data in? It would help to provide a reproducible sample.

Comment: it's just in a single field from a csv uploaded to R. I'm using R to compute the regex.

Comment: does the name always follow the pattern [initial].[lastname]? If so you could just use something like `'\\w\\.\\S+'`

Comment: yep! that worked! thank you.

Comment: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
  s = c("(6:57) K.Collins pass incomplete short right to A.Crumpler. Coverage by #56 Woodley, #22 Gay.", "(6:52) (Shotgun) K.Collins pass incomplete short right to B.Scaife (T.Polamalu).")
  str_extract_all(s, '([A-Z]([a-z]+)?\\.[A-Z][a-z]+)')[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this expression might likely work here, if we wish to capture the first name:

```
.*?\s+(\S+\.[A-Z][a-z]+).*
```

using this capturing group `(\S+\.[A-Z][a-z]+)`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lmeSZZ/1/)

and our code might look like:

```
gsub(".*?\\s+(\\S+\\.[A-Z][a-z]+).*", "\\1", input_goes_here)
```